# How do I get Gmail API to list messages in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth, google-apis-explorer

I used listMessages to get the Id and getMessages to print the snippet, however it doesn't seem to work:

```
      function listMessages() {
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      'maxResults': 1000,
      'userId': 'me',
      'format': 'full',

    }).then(function(response) {
      appendPre('Files:');
      var messages = response.result.messages;
      if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
          var message = messages[i];
          var message_Id = message.id;
          window.message_Id = message_Id;
          getMessages();

        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
      }
    });
  }
  function getMessages() {
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
      'maxResults': 1000,

      'id': message_Id,
      'userId': 'me',
      'format': 'full',

    }).then(function(response) {

      var messages = response.result.messages;
      if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
          var message = messages[i];

          appendPre(message.threadId + ' (' + message.snippet + ')');
        }
       else {
        appendPre('No files found.');

      }
    });
  }
```

For some reason it only returns with no files found, how can I get it to print out the snippet and Id?

Answer (score 1):

First, I did this steps https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

After That, I did like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

class ReadEmail {
  constructor(_dominio) {
    this.credentials = null;
    this.auth = null;
    this.message = null;
    this.dominio = _dominio;
  }

  async setup() {
    this.credentials = await this.getCredentials();
    this.auth = await this.getAuthorize();
    this.message = await this.getLastMessage();
  }

  getCredentials() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) reject('Error loading client secret file:' + err);
        resolve(JSON.parse(content));
      });
    });
  }

  getAuthorize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = this.credentials.installed;
      const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
      fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) reject('Erro ao pegar o Token: ' + err);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        resolve(oAuth2Client);
      });
    });
  }

  getLastMessage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: this.auth });
      var request = gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: 'me',
        labelIds: 'INBOX',
        maxResults: 10,
      });
      request.then(ret => {
        let id = ret.data.messages[0].id;
        var request2 = gmail.users.messages.get({
          userId: 'me',
          id: id,
        });
        request2.then(ret2 => {
          let msg = ret2.data.payload.body.data;
          let buff = new Buffer.from(msg, 'base64');
          let text = buff.toString('ascii');
          console.log(text)
          resolve(text);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
new ReadEmail('_dominio').setup();
```

Comment: Please include the first steps in your answer. Do not rely on external websites. You can add a link as reference/source, but don't post answers that are incomplete without external resources or that require users to go somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

To understand better, try following the quickstart for [JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), this shows a simple JavaScript application that makes requests to the Gmail API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listLabels();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': 'me'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var labels = response.result.labels;
          appendPre('Labels:');

          if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
              var label = labels[i];
              appendPre(label.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No Labels found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Things to remember:

- Turn on the Gmail API
- After the initial user authorization, calls to **`gapi.auth.authorize`** that use **`immediate:true`** mode will obtain an auth token without user interaction.

Also follow the links for further reading :

- [Google Developers Console help documentation](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/)
- [Google APIs Client for JavaScript documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/)
- [Gmail API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/)

This will help you understand and familiarize yourself with the different methods and function in Gmail API.